# Encode a Lenguage

Tags: code-challenge, encoding, open-ended-function, self-referential

The [Len(language,encoding)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Len(language,encoding)) family of languages is a variety of [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) derivatives. To encode a program into a Len language, you replace every character with its representation in a certain encoding, then turn that into a giant integer.

Your challenge is to write a function or program that encodes your language into a Len language. However, you can make up your own encoding, and it only needs to encompass the subset of your language that is used in your program. **But, you must have at least two distinct bytes in your program.**

## Rules

Your program must be able to take itself as input.

You can just output a number as the length of the compiled program, to avoid memory problems.

**Your program must be reversible.**

## Scoring

Your score is the result of your program run on itself. You're trying to minimise this.

Comment: [Sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22286#22286)

Comment: I feel like there are some restrictions missing on the encoding to stop solutions from hard-coding themselves as 1 (or hard-coding everything as 1, for that matter)--or at the least they're not spelled out quite enough

Comment: I agree with @UnrelatedString. I know that your intention was golf, but this is more of a "my encoding encodes my program as 0 and everything else in UTF-8" challenge.

Comment: Can it encode different programs as the same number? Or does it have to strictly follow the algorithm of setting a unique encoding for each symbol.

Comment: You should've required this encoding to be reversible, otherwise an obvious joke answer like Makonede's is actually valid

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That's not a joke answer actually, that was competing - and slightly abusing the restrictions, or rather lack thereof

Comment: So I'm still not sure I understand. Is it just an issue of converting a program into an integer in a manner that is reversible? Or *how* we do it also enforced, ie that we do it by replacing the characters with codepoints and then converting that?

Comment: Are we allowed to encode two different programs as the same number? Mine does. I know AviFS already commented above but just wanted to bring up the issue again.

Comment: Do we have to encode the empty program?

Comment: Can it just reverse into a program with different ode but samemeaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 40 bytes, score 0

```sh
grep -FqxfI $0&&od||od -An<I|tr -c 0-7 8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@G/n@T@9KLVAQdetsCLNU0HFQE0tP6WmJj9FQdcxz8azpqRIQTdZwUDXXMHiP9EqAQ)

Encodes itself as 0, and all other programs in some horrendous octal/decimal mishmash. Takes input from a file `I`.

- `grep`: search for a string that matches

  - `F`: exactly (non-regex)
  - `x`: the whole line
  - `fI`: the pattern taken from the `f`ile `I`
  - `q`: do not print the matching string; only exit with success or failure
  - `$0`: this source code file
- `&&od`: if the match succeeds, print `0000000`
- `||`: otherwise:

  - `od -An<I`: encode the input file in octal
  - `|tr -c 0-7 8`: replace all characters except `01234567`s with `8`s (ensures it's a valid number with no leading 0s)

Doesn't support newlines (nor null bytes).

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant. That comment has been there for a while, but no one had actually done it! I'm going to incorporate this into my answer.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7845</s> <s>535</s> 34

```
BC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyRmEAQ)

This converts the input from base `2` according to 05AB1E's codepage. `B` is mapped to 11 and `C` to 12. Digits larger or equal to the base are allowed and *"overflow"* into the next digit.
This can be inverted by iterating the digits of the output in reverse:

```
[D0Q#    "loop while TOS != 0"\
2‰`      "divmod 10"\
i        "if the last digit was 1:"\
 'Bˆ5-   "append ö to global array and subtract 5 from TOS"\
ë        "else:"\
 'Cˆ6-   "append T to global array and subtrac 6 from TOS"\
]¯RJ     "after the loop: reverse global array and join"\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY89bsJAFIT7nGKyFKmQIIALJBpCRRPx00GkPONns9HCWrsLiI6Ky6RIKg4Ql75FLmLWGEVIkZhyNO97M9pSKLkoZoPGqAYvobROsVtKxZi@TvDYQ0PMH55/D9/vuEhEcrvSEZqlL3GVkDHckqHIOkQykQ47smh2fQhP/fzYqZcpSlNeR8hOcBqJ0iEpkDG0B3nbbkJnaOHQQWz0qizgz7PPvyesLFfEl/wY3BKn94AIbnlvP1/jYcWj2LGpevvZXRjesrH8H/Sh5VrMi6LVPgM)

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>11 bytes, score 96697523013522</s> 14 bytes, score 10230313233344

```
⭆Ｓ⌕´Ｓ´⭆´⌕´´´ιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///R2rb3ezY/6pl6aAuQPrQFyAcSIC4Intt5bicxagA) Explanation: Now uses @AviFS's approach of looking up the possible characters in a table. However, the table itself more than triples the length of the code, which leaves no room to do base conversion, so instead I just output the digits individually as base 10, but fortunately it's still slightly lower than my original score.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), ~7.0689*10^69

```r
cat(utf8ToInt(scan(,''))-29,sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO0JM0iJN8zr0SjODkxT0NHXV1TU9fIUqc4tcAWyCZKDQA)

Converts the input to ASCII codepoints, subtracts 29, and concatenates all the 2-digit numbers obtained. I chose 29 because the lowest ASCII codepoint I need is 39 (for `'`); this ensures that all the numbers are between 10 and 98. Reversing is thus easy: split into groups of 2 digits, add 29 and convert back to characters.

Works on any string which does not include the characters  `!"#$%&`.

A [more naïve implementation](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO0JM0iJN8zr0SjODkxT0NHXV1TU6c4tcAWyCCsAAA) would omit the `-29` and use the plain ASCII codepoints; it is easy to convince oneself that this remains reversible even with some 3-digit numbers, but it leads to a score of 9.997*10^75.

Comment: This is great, but seems to be code-golfing rather than seriously competing using the challenge's scoring system.  Modifying your approach [like this](https://tio.run/##1ZDBasNADETv/gp1e/AKNiXpqalxIORU8KW0x0IjO7K7kOwuKzmQr3edln5CD7mN5sFImjz5cPbi2yPbt4s8COsxdjRPHSkPMV@gBtPsPrdNYxz8squ1M4hTudhQ1daJRHlp5XWMypbQEVZSZ6ZD4wOLdSus9r7fW7mrWzcH21H7p/f4EtQKLh7XTjjVxuAPWyL@V@7NHVwUV1F@hBKLe8icmBTaUUG/vID6E8PgzwwEB9/3nDkopByHTCewfczggyiFjh2YlP28ZoUGgWQGadTn4uYK@fti@gY) would give a score of zero...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I hadn't thought of such an approach (though I now see that other answers have used it since); you should post it! Although currently yours isn't reversible, since e.g. the inputs `T` and `""` both lead to the output `55`.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I think yours is reversible with `-23` instead of `-29`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2.7370885894231567 * 10^18

This is the most naive algorithm I could come up with, so I suppose it sets a baseline. Given the structure `{n⊥n|⎕UCS⍵}`, I wrote a script to check the lowest that *n* could be, and 28 is our answer.

That is, the lowest that *n* could be and still yield a unique codepoint for each symbol in the program, when it's unicode is reduced mod *n*.

The program simply takes the unicode codepoint of each symbol, mods it by 28, and then converts it to base 28. It's not very clever or optimized, I challenge you to be less lazy!

```apl
{28⊥28|⎕UCS⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pAwKO2CcYmCo965yoEp5YoFBSlJmcWZ@bnKWRkpmcolOQrFKemKhQn5xel/k8DKq02snjUtdTIogaoN9Q5@FHv1lqQMUCZNHUscupgg/1LSwpKS6CmAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes, score 81040998233

```
`\`\\v\ḟ6\β`vḟ6β
```

[Try it online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3F%60%3F%5C%60%5C%5Cv%5C%E1%B8%9F7%5C%CE%B2%60v%E1%B8%9F7%CE%B2&inputs=%3F%60%3F%5C%60%5C%5Cv%5C%E1%B8%9F7%5C%CE%B2%60v%E1%B8%9F7%CE%B2&header=&footer=)

There may be better languages to do this, but the idea is simple.

The other answers reduce the codepoints mod *n* where *n* is the smallest number that will yield unique codepoints. But that's rarely an efficient encoding. You usually end up with lots of numbers unused. Eg. your program becomes *[6,3,9,7,2]* rather than *[0,1,2,3,4]*.

This just packs every symbol used into a list, and for each symbol in the program, gets its index in the list. So you're guaranteed to get the lowest numbers you can: *[0..n]*. In addition, the symbols in the list are in the order they appear in the program, because we want the lower numbers to show up first. In every base, *[0,1,2,3]* is a much smaller number than *[3,2,1,0]*. Finally, I used 6 unique symbols, so I converted it to base 6.

**Example execution with `v6ḟ` as input:**

```
               # Implicit input                          -> "v6ḟ"
`\`\\v\ḟ6\β`   # This is just the string "`\vḟ6β" [1]    -> "v6ḟ", "`\vḟ6β"
vḟ             # Vectorized find index in list           -> [2,4,3]
6β             # Convert list to base 6                  -> 99
               # Implicit output
```

[1]: Unfortunately for this challenge, non-ASCII characters have an  (really cool) encoding scheme in strings. So in order to have them interpreted literally, all the non-ASCII characters in the string are escaped, which adds many orders of magnitude to the score.

Comment: Wait, you so deserve to post that as your own. I don't even get it. Mind explaining in the Vyxal chat?

Comment: I just realised it's invalid because leading 0s, otherwise [this](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%E2%80%9B%CE%B2%E2%80%9B%CE%B2&inputs=%E2%80%9B%CE%B2%E2%80%9B%CE%B2&header=&footer=) would work as well

Comment: From Charcoal's point of view the duplication to create the table is very expensive and I was only just able to achieve a lower result by skipping the base conversion completely!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 176 bytes, score=0

```r
'->a;b=paste0(sQuote(a),a);s=readLines(,1);`if`(s==b,cat(0),cat(utf8ToInt(s)-24,sep=""))'->a;b=paste0(sQuote(a),a);s=readLines(,1);`if`(s==b,cat(0),cat(utf8ToInt(s)-24,sep=""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZDBSsNAEIbveYphPWQXttKKBzGsID0JuYgeBTtJJ3Gg3V12JoU@fUwVH8FDT8PMBx//P2XmeGLh7kD27Sy3QnpIPS5bj0pjKmcIYNrt53PbGg@/7HLaGufmevWETRcyitLayuuUlCw6j66RUAj3LUcS6zeu2fGwsxJC5xexXbufMenw8J5eolpxq7t7L5SDWcT/5b26wFV1ofVHrF11A4UyoUI3KegXCygfCUY@ESDseRioUFTIJY0Fj2CHVICjKMaePJhcePFvnHGAsoA86WN1dQ/5azF/Aw)

Despite the enormously increased byte-count, this is basically just an extension of [Robin Ryder's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230013/95126), optimized for the challenge's scoring system instead of for `code-golf`.

We first construct a quine string of the program (`'...'->a;b=paste0(sQuote(a),a)`) in variable `b`, and then check if this is equal to the input (`` s=readLines(,1);`if`(s==b,... ``).   If it is, we output zero (`cat(0)`): that is, we hard-code this particular progam as zero.  Otherwise, we use [Robin's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230013/95126) to output the program's numerical value, which can never be less than `10`.

Valid programs can only use characters with ASCII values 34-123: so, no newlines, and no "`|}~`" characters.  The 'empty program' is not valid for this version (it also encodes to zero), but a [slight modification](https://tio.run/##3ZC/asMwEMZ3P8WhDtaBUpLSodS4UDIVvJR2LDSyc3YEsSR050Ce3rVTPPQFOng67vu4P98vjc5fHLv6TPrjyvdMcg6NnbrGCnUhXaEEVe2/X6tKGfj1ZmmvEMd882KLuoyWhbaa34cgpC0aiwWXieyxcp5Ymx0WB9ceNJelUmbarHdoFqW@CVu8lUHap8/w5kUzbh4eDVOcRhDxH0@tNFaWzXb@5XPM7iBRJCtQDwJycgzieoLOXQgsHF3bUiIvEFPoku1BtyGB8yzWN2RAxeT8/IJCsDwZcZDnbKXYlqx/@YVBptAwc5ETAfVRrguu1aLIxh8) can fix this, while keeping a score of zero for this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes, score 0 bytes

```
“Ṿ;⁾v,;⁾¥ ¤-iⱮḅL{ɗ⁼?ʋ/+1”v,¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZP2rcV6YDIg8tVTi0RDfz0cZ1D3e0@lSfnP6ocY/9qW59bcNHDXPLdIDS/8nRBAA)

Returns 0 when supplied itself as an input. Otherwise looks up the supplied input in the characters `“Ṿ;⁾v,;⁾¥ ¤-iⱮḅL{ɗ⁼?ʋ/+1”v,¥`  and converts back from bijective base 29 before adding 1 (so that an empty input will result in 1 rather than being the same as the encoder itself).

Inspired by [@pxeger’s Zsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230016/42248)  so be sure to upvote that one too (implementation quite different though).

[Decoder - Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8yHO5qNLB/u7j7V/XDn7EM77R81zHm4c5/1o8Z9ZTog8tBShUNLdDMfbVz3cEerT/XJ6Y8a99if6tbXNnzUMBessmFOmQ5QFZB7aMn///@NDCzMzQA)

### Explanation

#### Main link

```
“Ṿ…”v,¥  | Evaluate this string as a Jelly link with itself paired to the overall link’s argument (the program to encode)
```

#### Code run within eval

```
                   ʋ/   | Reduce using the following:
Ṿ                       | - Uneval (effectively wraps the string in “”)
 ;⁾v,;⁾¥ ¤              | - Append "v,¥ " (thus restoring the source for the encoder)
                 ⁼?     | - If equal to the original argument (the program to encode):
          -             |   - Then -1
                ɗ       |   - Else:
           iⱮ           |     - Indices of each character of program to encode in the string
             ḅ          |     - Convert from base given by:
              L{        |       - The length of the string
                     +1 | Add 1
```

Note the program has a trailing space because of the need to use `⁾` within `“”` which takes a pair of characters.

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes, score 7842

```
OḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/3DnKmuHhzuaHu7uftS4z//hjhb/Y10Pdy30OLQ05liXyollhycc2u/2cOe0hzu6Hu7uebhz1n@Qov86h9sf7lzrcLjd6eGOHqAOMNvwyH4VLmOjhzu2OSHMO9yu8qhpjTcQR/4HAA)

A monadic link that converts to Unicode code points and unbinaries. This is a similar approach as [@ovs’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230017/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too!

The TIO link includes a decoder in the header and generates a table of the first 32 possible programs including their decimal representation and the decoded program.